# How to use devise gem for authentication in API-only Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to create a rails API with the devise gem for authentication.
I am using Chrome Postman to check API outputs.

My environments:

- Rails 4.2
- Ruby 2.3

What I did:

1. ran

   ```sh
   rails new my_api
   cd my_api
   ```
2. added devise gem in `Gemfile`
3. `bundle install`
4. added

   ```ruby
   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
   ```

   to `environment/development.rb`
5. created one user using `rails console`

After that I tried to login from postman.
I gave `email` and `password` into headers of postman.

```
POST  http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
```

*headers*

email    **abcd@gamilcom**

password **abcd1234**

but it's not authenticating.  What do I need to do?

Comment: go through devise token base authentication https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth

Comment: Thank You   Pardeep Dhingra  it worked

Answer (score 14):

You may want to use [knock](https://github.com/nsarno/knock) or [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) in an API context. Be carreful, your email seems to be invalid. I don't know Postman but the POST parameters should live in the body of your HTTP request.

Comment: Note that `knock` doesn’t support OAuth, and `devise_token_auth` requires cookies to work.

Comment: speaking of JWT (and devise): This article was very helpful for me [Stop using JWT for sessions](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/). I'm still using Rails Session Cookies for API Authentication

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Basic Auth is turned off by default on Devise. It is simple to enable it and for most API purposes, basic auth is sufficient.

You need to do two things to enable HTTP basic auth:

- `:database_authenticatable` strategy in your user/account model
- `config.http_authenticatable = true` in the devise initializer

See more here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-HTTP-Basic-Authentication